# Daily personal task management tool

Tags: project-management, todo

I'm trying **to get an overview** of all the different personal task management tools out there. Therefore I'm grateful for **any** suggestion regarding this matter even if the criteria aren't matched. There are two features however which I'm looking for in particular:

1. The focus of the tool should be the management of my personal daily tasks. I'm not looking for an agile project management tool.
2. Less important but still a focus would be the access of Jira (or other agile project management tools like redmine, taiga.io or the like) tasks to put them into a more personal task list.

I'm still happy for suggestions which don't provide (1) or (2) as I'm mostly looking on getting an overview of **what people like to use personally for their individual daily task management**.

Ideally it should run on as many platforms as possible, web and/or offline would also be nice but that's also by no means a requirement.

To give you a rough idea what I'm looking for: [Simple Tasklists](https://marketplace.atlassian.com/plugins/com.topshelfsolution.simpletasklists/server/overview) comes pretty close, but it has to be installed with Jira itself, so I can't really use it for something else.

Comment: Welcome to Software Recommendations! We will need much more information to give good recommendations here. Please take a look at [What is required for a question to contain "enough information"?](//meta.softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/q/336/185) Then please [edit] your question and see if you can incorporate some of these improvements. Especially missing: What OS should it run on (or should it be a web-app)? What's your price margin (or should it be free as in "free beer")? What other specific features (apart from "working with Jira") do you need?

Comment: Do you need to edit tasks offline?

Comment: "or other agile project management tool": Do you mean that if the tool supports GNATS then it does not need to support JIRA?

Comment: Elsewhere I saw the kanban concept recommended.  You make columns, such as To Do, In Process, Complete; and then you drag little things like post-its around.  Would something like that work?

Answer (score 0):

The best task management app I know of is [Quire](https://quire.io). The free version is very functional. Wonderful interface on both web and Android.

Comment: Hello, are you associated with that? SInce you recommended it few times in quick succession. You need to provide that information then.

Comment: No. No affiliation. I asked my first question here and so wanted to contribute something back to the site. Quire is one app I use a lot and can highly recommend. So I went looking for some task management questions I could contribute to.